# Regular expression for a formatted time

Tags: regex

I have a time format that I want to check if it is correct. The format should be [H]H.MM[a|p]. Hours should be from 1 to 12, minutes as usual and the ending character either an `a` or `p`. There should also be a dot between the hours and minutes.

I tried with this reg ex, but it didn't work:

```
var reg = /^([1-9|10|11|12])\.[0-5][0-9][pa]$/;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant

```
var reg = /^([1-9]|10|11|12)\.[0-5][0-9][pa]$/;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
^([1-9]|10|11|12)\.[0-5][0-9][ap]$
```